# In Go, how do you convert a [16]float32 to *float32

Tags: arrays, pointers, go

I am using a math library to handle projection matrix arithmetic.

The OpenGL library that I am using requires "*float32" that represents the matrix.
However, what I have available is "[16]float32"

How can I create a *float32 variable and have it point to the beginning of the [16]float32 array?

Thanks.

Comment: `unsafe.Pointer(&var[0])` (cast as required)

Answer (score 1):

working sample:

```
package main

/*
float Add(float *fs)
{
  fs[15]=15.5;
  return fs[0]+fs[1];
}
*/
import "C"

import "fmt"
import "unsafe"

func main() {
    ary := [16]float32{1.5, 2.0}
    fs := (*C.float)(unsafe.Pointer(&ary[0]))
    r := float32(C.Add(fs))
    fmt.Println(r, ary[15]) //3.5 15.5
}
```